# Word request: Responding to a question with a non-answer by stating the obvious or taking the question too literally

Tags: word-choice, terminology

I'm looking for a word or phrase that describes someone answering a question by intentionally stating the obvious or taking the question too literally, thereby insulting the person who asked the question (by implying that they asked a stupid question).

For example:

> Questioner (holding package): "Who is this package for?"
>
> Respondent: "Whoever it's addressed to"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use ***facetious*** to describe the person answering.

The definition given by [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/facetious) is *joking or jesting*, but in use facetious often has the undertone that the comment was inappropriate.

The words ***flippant*** or ***glib*** also work.

Comment: *Facetious* is good.

Comment: I like _flippant_, as I think it better describes the "mean" or "cruel" intent I'm trying to describe.

Comment: @WordLover1337 You've got them the wrong way round, a _facetious_  remark is more often meant to hurt or belittle someone, a _flippant_ remark merely indicates a lack of seriousness with respect to the subject.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward term for it would be *evasion*:

> **evasion** noun [ C or U ]
>   ​
>   the act of avoiding something or someone:
>
> - Her speech was full of excuses and evasions and never properly addressed the issue.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/evasion)

However, a psychological term would be *passive aggression*:

> **passive-aggressive** adjective
>
> Of or denoting a type of behaviour or personality characterized by indirect resistance to the demands of others and an avoidance of direct confrontation.

[Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/passive-aggressive)